# Pass the value from WithLatestFrom to another operator - Rxjs, Ngrx effect

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I've got this ngrx effect and I want to use the data from my state using `withLatestFrom`.

```
$loadProduct = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromSelectors.debounceTime)),
    delay(debounceTime), // how can I get the debounceTime value up here?
    map(_ => fromActions.foo())
  )
)
```

How can I get this debounceTime value within the scope of delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$loadProduct = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromSelectors.debounceTime)),
    switchMap(([_, debounceTime]) => timer(debounceTime)),
    map(_ => fromActions.foo())
  )
)
```

It's using RxJS's [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) and [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) instead of delay.

By the way, if you do not need the action somewhere in the subsequent part of the pipe, you may also use switchMap instead of withLatestFrom like this:

```
$loadProduct = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    switchMap(() => this.store.select(fromSelectors.debounceTime)),
    switchMap(debounceTime => timer(debounceTime)),
    map(() => fromActions.foo())
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `delay` is just [`delayWhen(() => timer(duration));`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delay.ts#L56), I think you can use `delayWhen` to solve the problem:

```js
$loadProduct = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromSelectors.debounceTime)),
    
    delayWhen(([, debounceTimeVal]) => timer(debounceTimeVal)),

    map(_ => fromActions.foo())
  )
)
```

As a side note, `delayWhen` is just [an interesting use case of `mergeMap`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/0b9b5fdb3731f632dcd3b9f52e6a88f4a198cb4a/src/internal/operators/delayWhen.ts#L89): instead of emitting the inner value, the outer value is emitted instead.